# C# WPF Open a window, but checkboxes are not set

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

i have a problem with my Checkboxes.
I have a MainWindow(), from here i open my second Window to set some searchpropertys for the user. 
(in wich fields they want to search ... like Name, Firstname and other)
After the user confirmed his choices, the Window get closed and the values get saved in the app.propertys.
On the next start up of the application the values from the session before are still how they should be, so this part works.

Now the problem:
If i now open the Window all the Checkboxes arnt set like they should be?! 
I have them bound to my ViewModel like this :

```
 <CheckBox x:Name="cVersichertenstatus" Content=...  **IsChecked="{Binding Versichertenstatuschecked}"** .../>
```

The code for my bindings lock like this:

```
private bool versichertenstatusischecked;

        public bool Versichertenstatuschecked
        {
            get
            {
                return versichertenstatusischecked;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Versichertenstatuschecked != value)
                {
                    versichertenstatusischecked = value;
                    //this.OnPropertyChanged("Versichertenstatuschecked");
                }
            }
        }
```

After the start up i set all the binding propertys with the values of the app.propertys. 
But it change nothing. The Checkboxvalues are always false :-(

I guess its because i dont use OnPropertyChanged, but if i try i get this error:

```
object reference not set to an instance of the object
```

I dont get it, i have alot of bindings and all work fine, only the checkbox things do not.

Can someone explain me what i have to do to resolve this error?

Edit:

```
Set the Datacontext :
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupBindings();
            var l = new app_config_load();
            l.load();

        }

        private void SetupBindings()
        {
            pViewModelList viewModel = new pViewModelList();
            plistview.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
```

and the load() class:

```
  public void load()
            {
                Properties.Settings get = new Properties.Settings();
                pViewModelList a = new pViewModelList();

                a.Nachnamechecked = get.cnachname_app;
                a.Versichertenstatuschecked = get.cversichertenstatus_app;
                a.Geburtsdatumchecked = get.cgeburtsdatum_app;
                a.Versicherungsnrchecked = get.cversichertennummer_app;
                a.Vornamechecked = get.cvorname_app;
                get.Save();
            }
```

Do i have to initialize somehow the Propertys first? Thought this happens automaticly ?!

Comment: What are you using to bind the data to the View? Prism? MVVMLight? Or have you just implemented OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: Which implementation of `OnPropertyChanged` did you use? If you implemented it yourself, please post the code. (And: just in case you used `DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged()` by deriving your ViewModel class from `DependencyObject`, that would be wrong.)

Comment: Hi, i have a ViewModelBase that provide OnPropertyChange. Its from this side http://www.cocktailsandcode.de/2012/04/mvvm-tutorial-part-4-viewmodel/.

Comment: If you are not calling `OnPropertyChanged`, the changes will not be notified to the UI. So, you have to call that in your setter. Now, why are you getting that error, for that we need to know, how are assigning the `DataContext` and when and moreover have you initialized the object which you have assigned to the `DataContext`. One more thing, if there is any Collection or List object present there in the `DataContext`, you have to specifically create a new of it.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the "object reference not set to an instance of the object" exception? In the commented-out line? (I am asking because I can see no reason how the `OnPropertyChanged()` call could cause this exception.)

Comment: Hi, thats how i set the Datacontext. After i set the Context i use the l.load() class to set the propertys (like this in the starting post):  public MainWindow(){
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupBindings();
            var l = new app_config_load();
            l.load();

        }

        private void SetupBindings()
        {
            pViewModelList viewModel = new pViewModelList();
            plistview.DataContext = viewModel;
        }

Comment: Mhm cant i use code on Answers?

Comment: Yes, it happens at the outcommented line @fmunkert

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the DataContext?

```
public MyWindow(MyClass myClass){
InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = myClass;
}
```

Before InitializeComponent(); all of your GUI - Elements will be null!

How to get your Element from MainWindow:

```
public MyClass GetData()
{
  MyClass data = this.DataContext as MyClass;
  return data;
}
```

and try:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=Versichertenstatuschecked}"
```

Comment: Hi, i initialzie the Components before i do the other stuff and the context is set.

Comment: Did you try the following: IsChecked="{Binding Path=Versichertenstatuschecked}"

Comment: Yes, i did. Was the same at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is. You miss the `Mode` of the binding.

```
IsChecked="{Binding Versichertenstatuschecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Using this will trigger changes in the viewModel to be displayed in the view.

Comment: Hi, that didnt solved the problem. I guess its because i dont use OnPropertyChanged, but i have realy no idea why its cause me the Object refernece problem :(

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by my self.
I just needed to wait till the Window is loaded before i use my Class to set the bindingpropertys.
I used the "loaded" event to call the Class and jeah, no longer any Object Reference errors :)

Such things are realy frustrating.

Cya